# Find an equation of the curve that is the intersection of the sphere.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, spheres

I have a sphere defined by this $(x-2)^2+(y-1)^2+z^2=8$ and I need to find an equation for the curve that *is* the intersection of said sphere **and** the xy-plane.

After finding that equation I would need to describe the figure and graph it. I'm assuming this will be a 2D picture/sketch rather than in 3D.

I'm not even sure where to start with this one since all the examples I can find that relate to this material deal with simpler problems.

I wish I could show some work for this first, but I am truly lost for what to do. All I can show is $center=(2, 1, 0)$ and $radius=2\sqrt{2}$

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You actually already have the answer...you might not recognize it yet.  The equation for the xy plane is $z = 0$ plugging this into the equation above and what do you get?

Comment: @DougM Ah, that makes sense. So it is as if the sphere was cut. All that is left is $(x-2)^2+(y-1)^2=8$ a circle. Thank you for your help. If you make your comment into an answer then I can accept that as the answer. One question though, won't it be a cylinder?

Comment: Yes, the lone equation is that of a cylinder, but you’re forgetting the second equation that you already have: $z=0$. The system of these two equations describes a curve.